# CSS Menu Issues

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, themes

I have a web site running locally in IIS. I also copied the exact same files and folder structure to a web server.

The remotely deployed code works fine, but the local installation appears to have a CSS issue. It appears to be having a problem finding a theme file.

When I run the app in the IDE, my javascript drop down menus, appear all white/imnvisible, which suggests also a theme or CSS issue. But when I deploy the code to a local IIS web folder and access it thru IE, I get the following error.

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Theme 'U-Net' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.

Source Error: 


Line 14:   </configSections>
Line 15:   <system.web>
Line 16:     <pages masterPageFile="~/SysAdmin.Master" theme="U-Net">
Line 17:       <controls>
Line 18:         <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Yet, the theme file that it cannot find appears to be where it should be [(See image)](http://screencast.com/t/ODEwY2ZlM) and I am confused why to deployments that appear identical get different results.

[Here's](http://screencast.com/t/NjkwMzQwZ) and image of the folder structure of the remote server where it works.

I used a comparison tool to compare the dir structure and the file contents of both local and remote web sites. There is [no difference](http://screencast.com/t/MjdmYjg4N).

Can anyone spot what the difference may be or suggest what to check?

[Check out](http://screencast.com/t/M2VkNTRj) the local IIS configuration.

Not sure about what the "Create App" button does for me. I thought I usually run with this option. Not sure how it is set on the remote server, I don't have rights to it.

Strange: When I push the Create app button for the Virtual folder in IIS 5, I get this error when I try to access the site.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   SysAdmin.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

The site needs to use Windows Authentication.[This](http://screencast.com/t/MWFmOThmNzIt) is the security.

Thanks for getting to the end of this long post. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Somewhere, IIS is  configured wrong.

Comment: Double check that SysAdmin is a Virtual Directory / Application (depending on your version of IIS).

Comment: I edited the original post to add a little more info about the IIS setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but I reinstalled IIS and everything worked again. Although, when I tried to create a site on another drive, I had the same issue. However, reinstalling IIS fixed my primary web site default location under inetpub, so I guess I relatively happy.